# How to setup a grunt project?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My node and git installed on the following directory:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\npm
```

I want to setup a grunt project for which I read instructions from http://gruntjs.com/getting-started It says:

Working with an existing Grunt project

1. Change to the project's root directory (Can anyone please explain?)
2. Install project dependencies with npm install.
3. Run Grunt with grunt.

Preparing a new Grunt project, setup will involve adding two files to our project:

1. package.json
2. Gruntfile

When I use cli `$ grunt build` on git, it errors: **Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.**

Basically, I just want to kick off my project but not even able to install. Can anyone explain or suggest resource so I can setup and start work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install the `grunt-cli` package via `npm` using the `-g` flag yet?

Comment: @m90 yes, I did ( `$ npm install grunt-cli -g` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably need to install grunt cli

```
npm i grunt-cli -g
```

next install

```
npm i grunt -g
```

this is for plugins and related stuff

more info from http://hiking.luddites.me/2013/07/making-sense-of-grunt-importing.html

Comment: First of all `grunt-cli` needs to be installed.

Comment: Although I have in application data, I tried this command and later `$ grunt build' but get the same error :(

Comment: @m90 'Change to the project's root directory' Where I keep the project? I mean is it mandatory to keep the project at same location where the grunt exist?

Comment: @EugeneP 'Change to the project's root directory' Where I keep the project? I mean is it mandatory to keep the project at same location where the grunt exist?

Comment: http://hiking.luddites.me/2013/07/making-sense-of-grunt-importing.html

take a look

Comment: @Diya NOT mandatory, as -g specifies to install grunt globally. grunt just care about dependencies in package.json, if I'm not mistaken